Why are the top bar widgets links?
I noticed that the top bar widgets next to your profile, including your inbox, achievements, review, help, and communities, are actually links to the respective pages I have linked, in addition to being buttons that show a menu when they are clicked. This can be demonstrated by right clicking them and selecting Open Link in New Tab. Since the button behavior seems to override the link behavior normally, I do not see the purpose of them being links.
Right clicking on the communities menu offers Open Link in New Tab
This however does cause an annoyance, that if I try to click on one of these too quickly if my internet connection is too slow, I will be directed to the corresponding link rather than being shown the menu. If the page is not fully loaded, the behavior to show the menu might not have loaded yet.
So my question is, for what purpose do these widgets link to those corresponding pages, if most of the time the behavior is hidden by them being buttons to show a menu?

So they work if you've turned javascript off.
